# std::allocator<T>: Is constructing on unallocated memory in C++ allowed?

Tags: c++, allocator

So I am relatively new to C++, and I recently encountered the `std::allocator` class. I understand that this is a powerful tool used in creation of `vector`s, `list`s, `deque`s, etc. and I am trying to learn more about it. 
One thing that confuses me is the following:

For example, if we define some `allocator<int>` denoted as `alloc`, and we use it to allocate `n` locations in memory via `auto const b = a.allocate(n)`, where `b` is the pointer to the first `int` element in the allocated memory, then, one is also obliged to construct the allocated memory in order to actually access it, right?
If we introduce some iterating pointer `auto e=b`, then the construction can be performed via `alloc.construct(e++,int_obj)`, where `int_obj` is some user-initialized object of the type `int`. This is all nice and tame as long as the total amount of calls to `construct` is less than `n`. However, I am not quite sure what happens when the number of user calls to `construct` exceeds `n`. I initially expected some warning or error message to rear its ugly head, however nothing happened. As a simple example, here is the snipped of the code I tried to run:

```
int n{ 0 };                            // Size of the array is initialized to 0.
cin >> n;                              // User reads in the size.
allocator<int> alloc;                  // 'alloc' is an object that can allocate ints.
auto const b = alloc.allocate(n);      // Pointer to the beginning of the array. 
auto e = b;                            // Moving iterator that will point to the end of the array

for (int i = 0;i != 10;++i)
    alloc.construct(e++, i);           // We start constructing 10 elements in the array, regardless of the size n, which can in principle be less than 10.
for (auto i = b;i != e;++i)
    cout << *i << "\t";
```

Initially I run this code for `n=1`, and all works nice; it prints out digits from 0 to 9, even though I allocated space only for one digit. That is a red flag already, right? Then I change `n` to `2`, and program breaks after printing the digit number four, which is more what I expected.

What I conclude from this behavior is that trying to construct memory yet unallocated via `std::allocator` is undefined and unpredictable, and as such should be avoided (which is obvious to begin with). But, this seems as as extremely dangerous pitfall, and I wanted to know if there is some build-in workaround in C++ that will always prevent user when trying to construct unallocated memory.

Comment: C++ is not a memory-safe language. There are plenty of ways that you can produce _undefined behaviour_ - which may crash, or may do something unexpected, or may "work" as intended - this is one of them. The fact that it seems to "work" for n=1 is coincidence. In general, it's best to avoid manual allocation if possible. Especially, you should rarely need to use `allocator` directly; In this case `new int[n]` would do the job just fine. But then, many would say you should avoid "raw" arrays as well...

Comment: @davmac :  I am aware that one can dynamically allocate an array, but, as an exercise I try to emulate how simple vector class works. Vector class has a nice limitation, that will initially allocate some memory for followup elements, and whenever new element is added to the vector, new object in vector will be created in order to hold the element. However, there are cases when we want to add new element, but the space allocated previously is already full, so vector needs to know to allocate more memory. It does that without user's knowledge. This principle I want to understand.

Comment: In that case it allocates another (larger) array, copies/moves the elements from the original array into the new one, and deallocates the old one. It is never correct to allocate a certain amount of storage and then use more than what was allocated (even if it doesn't always cause a segmentation fault, it cannot be expected to behave in any reliable way).

Comment: have a look at this two links: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/008.htm  http://www.stroustrup.com/except.pdf

Comment: Yes, constructing an object on non-existent memory is a dangerous pitfall. It is the programmer's responsibility to ensure that doesn't happen, by using clean technique. Acommon guideline is to avoid any direct assignment/initialisation of a pointer using a `new` expression  (e.g. don't do `some_X = new X`), since it is easy to misuse such pointers (and therefore access unallocated memory).  Instead, use the standard library - specifically, standard containers (`vector`, `list`, `string`, etc) if you need a collection of objects, or `shared_ptr` to hold results of any `new` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, this seems as as extremely dangerous pitfall,

It certainly is, and it's your responsibility to avoid this pitfall. That's why it's always recommended to use existing containers first, because they've been carefully written, reviewed and tested to avoid such bugs.

If you do need to handle raw memory directly, it's generally better to write your own container which you can test to a similar standard, rather than interleaving manual memory management with the rest of your program logic.

> and I wanted to know if there is some build-in workaround in C++ that will always prevent user when trying to construct unallocated memory

No, because that necessarily incurs a runtime cost for something that was incorrect when it was written. I don't want my program to run slower because someone else is bad at *their* job.

However, there are plenty of tools to help you test and diagnose these bugs, for example:

- the clang and gcc compilers have address sanitizers which compile these checks into your program (it's an optional compiler facility rather than part of the language)
- valgrind is an external program whose default tool (memcheck) runs your real program looking for these bugs. It's slow, but it's used for testing or debugging and not for live programs